# Imgur | Retrieval of direct image urls given album link

Tags: javascript, imgur

I'm writing a simple js based webapp that is based around the displaying of images.

Ultimately, I want the user to be able to link an album url, let's say "https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWRwH.jpg", and I should be able to retrieve an individual image direct urls from that. So for this album the first one would be "https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3umV.jpg", "second image direct url", "third image direct url" etc.

Ideally, the method to do this should avoid API calls, as I'm trying to make this as light as possible.

Is such a thing even possible?

Comment: It looks like each image tag has an `id` attribute that corresponds to the image's url.

Comment: Because [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is disabled by default (and must be turned on for the domain that's going to share its resources), this is usually not possible unless you have your own server that can browse that page or the JS you're writing is running in a different environment from a browser. API's for websites are specifically using CORS and have defined ways that let you access their resources. So most likely, you will have to use their API's.

Comment: Hm... That makes sense. It looks like the best way to do it is to use the API. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the equivalent of this is in JavaScript, but I ended up using a shell command like this to do the same thing:

```
curl http://imgur.com/a/j1ddA|
grep -o '<div id="[^"]*" class="post-image-container'|
cut -d\" -f2|
sed 's,.*,http://i.imgur.com/&.jpg,'
```